# Proving a transformation is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If I have a transformation $T:V \to V$ given by $T(f(x)) = x*f(x)$. To prove this would I just show that $T(a*f(x_1) + b*f(x_2)) = a*T(f(x_1)) + b*T(f(x_2))$ to show addition and scalar multiplication work for the transformation? I wasn't sure if I would do $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ for this proof, am I right in doing it in this matter? The vector field is all functions f(x). By * I mean multiplication of vectors.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the question is not clear.

Comment: You should define for us what your vector space $V$ is (a space of functions?) and what the operation $*$ is (multiplication of functions?). You should also say in the statement of the problem (not just the title) exactly what you're trying to prove.

Comment: I want to prove T(f(x)) -> x*f(x) is a linear transformation. To do this, I want to show T(a*v + b*w) = a*T(v) + b*T(w). I wasn't sure if for functions I would have different functions instead of v and w or two arbitrary x's.

Comment: @GregMartin I editted with that information,sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you would like to prove the linearity of $T$, which is a map on a space of functions. For linearity one has to show that
$$ T(\alpha  f(x)+\beta g(x))=\alpha Tf(x)+\beta Tg(x) $$
holds for all numbers $\alpha, \beta$ and all functions $f, g \in V$.
In the above case we have
$$ T(\alpha  f(x)+\beta g(x))=x(\alpha  f(x)+\beta g(x))=\alpha x f(x)+\beta x g(x)=
\alpha Tf(x)+\beta Tg(x). $$